# Error running Jest test using vuejs-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, jestjs

I am learning Jest with my test Vue application and all was going ok with the exception that in one of my `components` I am using `vuejs-datepicker` and when I run the tests below I get the below error which I can't seem to get my head around to fix.

**Test file**

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import ShowBlogs from '@/components/showBlogs.vue'
import ActiveBlogs from '@/components/blogsActive.vue'
import AddBlog from '@/components/addBlog.vue'
import ClosedBlogs from '@/components/blogsClosed.vue'

describe('ShowBlogs.vue tests', () => {
    let wrapper = null

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(ShowBlogs)
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.destroy()
    })

    it('Checks "ShowBlogs" component rendered', () => {
        expect(wrapper.name()).toMatch('ShowBlogs')
    })

    it('Checks "Active" tab displayed on load', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(ActiveBlogs).exists()).toBeTruthy()
    })

    it('Checks tab labels & correct tab has "Active" class', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).toEqual('Articles')

        expect(wrapper.findAll('li').length).toEqual(3)
        expect(wrapper.findAll('li').at(0).text()).toEqual('Active blogs')
        expect(wrapper.findAll('li').at(1).text()).toEqual('Closed blogs')
        expect(wrapper.findAll('li').at(2).text()).toEqual('Add a new blog')

        expect(wrapper.find('#activeBlogs-tab').classes()).toContain('active')
    })

    it('Checks "ClosedBlogs" component displayed when clicking "Closed Blogs tab"', () => {
        wrapper.find('#closedBlogs-tab').trigger('click')
        expect(wrapper.find(ClosedBlogs).exists()).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

**Error**

> FAIL  tests/unit/showBlogs.vue.spec.js   ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>
> Here's what you can do:
>  • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.    
>  • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>  • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config
> ```
>
> option.
>
> ```
> You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
>
> Details:
>
> C:\Users\anton\Desktop\testProject\vueproject\node_modules\vuejs-datepicker\dist\vuejs-datepicker.esm.js:2437
> export default Datepicker;
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
>
>   116 | 
>   117 | <script>
> > 118 | import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker/dist/vuejs-datepicker.esm.js";
>       | ^
>   119 | //import * as lang from "vuejs-datepicker/src/locale";
>   120 | import globalVars from "../mixins/globalVars";
>   121 | import loader from './loader.vue';
>
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
>   at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
>   at src/components/addBlog.vue:118:1
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/addBlog.vue:232:3)
> ```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vueproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^3.16.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "firebase": "^7.9.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuefire": "^2.2.1",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

**Jest.config**

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest'
}
```

**AddBlog.vue**

```
<script>
import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker/dist/vuejs-datepicker.esm.js";
import globalVars from "../mixins/globalVars";
import loader from './loader.vue';
import moment from 'moment'
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

When you'll run the test, the Jest try to find the css files in lib DatePicker, you should to mock it.

Follow the steps:

```
mkdir tests/__mocks__/ && touch tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js
```

Note: the file *styleMock.js* will stay empty, because the file will be simulate tmp file.

After, you need to add the configuration in `jest.config.js`

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
  },
```

And the last, try to run your test again =)